# textarea value display in JSP - Struts2 - AppEngine

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, jsp, struts2

Form have `textarea` as input. Values are stored to appengine datastore. When displaying the value of the saved data, whitespace are not displayed. How to displaying including the whitespace?

In jsp I have:

```
<s:property value="user.aboutMySelf"/>
```

Whitespace like `\n` or newline is not displayed.

What is the best approach on this?

Comment: well though there are `escapeHTML` propert for some tags but it will not work for `\n` or `newlines` and you need to do it manually

Comment: you can even try replace thing like `<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="user.aboutMySelf.replace(\"\n\", \" <br />\")" />
`

Comment: when saved from `textarea`, i think it does not have `\n`.

Comment: Than you need to save an HTML the way you want only than you can display it in HTML formmat only

Comment: You need to replace newlines with break tags, or use a pre tag, etc to preserve whitespace. HTML doesn't show newlines in plain text, or preserve multiple spaces.